# Azure Web Jobs & run a python 3.9 console app

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a python console application that is written using python 3.9.4.
I was wondering if I could deploy and run this application using a Azure Web Job?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a python console application that is written using python 3.9.4. I was wondering if I could deploy and run this application using an Azure Web Job?

As you didn’t mention the App Service is of Windows or Linux OS type because Azure Web Job is the part of an Azure App Service as mentioned in the MS Q&A Forum - [808421](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/808421/how-to-deploy-python-codes-in-azure.html).

1. Python App Service is not supported on Windows OS Type.

[image]

2. Web Jobs is not supported in Linux Web Apps / App Services.

So, it is recommended to use the Azure Functions Service for running your Python Web Jobs (Scheduled) Scripts with the help of Timer Trigger Function.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python) for more information on Timer Trigger Python Function for running the scheduled scripts.